# How to transpose line up using SQL

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm looking for a way to transpose line up using SQL so that first table would looks like the second one.
I'm using Firebird 2.5

[image: Tabela]

Edit: Uploaded DDL and Insert

https://file.io/A6FRsB3jRJ99

https://file.io/aXFC0ltDohYP

https://file.io/ksSe34zCXSCF

https://file.io/MyqMik9oaqYV

https://file.io/zoRhLvIS2kn1

https://file.io/fCe8I62UfFtu

https://file.io/7DjGrJqGyfG9

https://file.io/LQq8xjYWB80s

https://file.io/JO9BmPITxDAu

https://file.io/JKM3Q7oFaz5h

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
FAIXA.CODIGO,
FAIXA.COD_COR,
FAIXA.DESC_COR,
FAIXA.POSICAO,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 1 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM1,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 1 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT1,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 2 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM2,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 2 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT2,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 3 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM3,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 3 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT3,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 4 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM4,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 4 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT4,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 5 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM5,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 5 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT5,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 6 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM6,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 6 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT6,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 7 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM7,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 7 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT7,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 8 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM8,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 8 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT8,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 9 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM9,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 9 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT9,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 10 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM10,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 10 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT10,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 11 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM11,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 11 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT11,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 12 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM12,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 12 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT12,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 13 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM13,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 13 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT13,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 14 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM14,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 14 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT14,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 15 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM15,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 15 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT15,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 16 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM16,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 16 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT16,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 17 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM17,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 17 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT17,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 18 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM18,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 18 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT18,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 19 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM19,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 19 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT19,
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 20 THEN (FAIXA.QTDE) END) AS TAM20, 
    (CASE WHEN FAIXA.POSICAO = 20 THEN (FAIXA.DT_FINAL) END) AS DT20
FROM
( 
    SELECT
    A.NUMERO,
    A.DT_FINAL,
    A.CODIGO,
    B.COR COD_COR,
    C.DESCRICAO DESC_COR,
    B.TAM,
    B.QTDE,
    D.POSICAO 
FROM
    OF1_001 A
INNER JOIN OF_ITEN_001 B ON
    B.NUMERO = A.NUMERO
INNER JOIN CADCOR_001 C ON 
    C.COR = b.COR
INNER JOIN PRODUTO_001 E ON 
    E.CODIGO = A.CODIGO 
INNER JOIN FAIXA_ITEN_001 D ON
    (D.FAIXA = E.FAIXA
        AND D.TAMANHO = b.TAM)
WHERE A.ID_TIPO IN ('5', '6')
AND b.QTDE > 0 
AND a.codigo in (:codigo)                                                  
) FAIXA
```

Comment: Your results seem to assume an ordering to the rows.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so the ordering is an issue.

Comment: Please provide the necessary DDL and insert statements to recreate this test data.

Comment: DDL, insert and select has been added.

Comment: Can you do it on client instead? Transposing means variable, unkjnown in advance number of columns. It is not what SQL was designed for, it is what reporting engines were designed for. Why not using tools to their purpose rather than abusing them?

Comment: Potential duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50723916 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449169 and many questions with "pivot" keyword instead of "transpose"

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but maybe something like this?

```
with t1 as (
  select codigo, cod_cor, des_cor, tam1, dt1,
      row_number() over (order by null) as rn
  from your table
  where tam2 is null and tam3 is null
),
t2 as (
  select codigo, cod_cor, des_cor, tam2, dt2
      row_number() over (order by null) as rn
  from your table
  where tam1 is null and tam3 is null
),
t3 as (
  select codigo, cod_cor, des_cor, tam3, dt3
      row_number() over (order by null) as rn
  from your table
  where tam1 is null and tam2 is null
)
select
  coalesce(t1.codigo, t2.codigo, t3.codigo) as codigo,
  coalesce(t1.cod_cor, t2.cod_cor, t3.cod_cor) as cod_cor,
  coalesce(t1.des_cor, t2.des_cor, t3.des_cor) as des_cor,
  t1.tam1,
  t1.dt1,
  t2.tam2,
  t2.dt2,
  t3.tam3,
  t3.dt3    
from t1 
  full join t2
    on t1.rn = t2.rn
  full join t3
    on t1.rn = t3.rn
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work... windowed functions are allowed from firebird 3 onwards